# How to read it $D_x^a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying a topic on simplest equation method. In the topic to define derivative there was a term
$$D_x^a$$
I want to know that how to read it?

Comment: "Dee sub ex to the ay"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking how to interpret the notation you presented.

The notation $D^a_x$ is describing a differential operator; this was a notation used by Euler.

It is equivalent to the more common Leibniz notation, ${d^a\over dx^a}$.

In Euler's notation, the subscript, *x* represents the variable of integration, while the "exponent" represents the order of the derivative.

You can read $D^a_x$ as the *a*th derivative of a function with respect to *x*. On that note, you are most likely to see this notation preceding, or otherwise referring to some function.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\dfrac{d^a}{dx^a}$, as in the *a*th derivative of a function with respect to *x*. The "exponent" (note the quotes) is actually an indicator of the order of the derivative you are taking. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Also $D^0_x f(x)=f(x)$. The "0th derivative" of $f$ is $f$ itself.